# Why do certain tags also go in tab title?

Tags: support, tags, question-titles

I am asking a question extending from this one: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6224/how-are-tags-ordered-and-why-only-the-first-one-is-included-in-the-question-titl:

Why for instance in this questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663425/how-to-put-a-box-around-something-in-gimp), when I only include the [gimp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gimp) tag I get this in the title (`title - site`):

[image]

So in fact no tag, but when I add the [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation), I get this (`tag - title - site`):

[image]

So how come when I only have the [gimp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gimp) I don't get any tag in the tab title, and when I have the [software-recommendations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) tag I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some quick observations, it seems to pick the first tag (ordered by populatiry, descending) that **isn't** already in the title. If **all** the tags are in the title, it won't prepend anything.

All the GIMP questions tagged only with [gimp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gimp), seem to have some form of "gimp" in their title. Which makes sense if you're asking a question about GIMP.

---

Using Data.SE, I found [an example where GIMP isn't in the title](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356422/all-lines-are-dotted) and [gimp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gimp) is the only tag. The tag **is** copied up into the title. Along with numerous other examples (that are far easier to find) this seems to prove my hypothesis.

Comment: That only really answers half of my question, how come when the [tag:software-recommendations] tag is removed, and only the [tag:gimp] tag remains, there is no tag displayed in the tab title?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Your question has GIMP in the title.

Comment: Indeed, the first paragraph seems to completely answer you question.

Comment: So if the word `GIMP` had not been in the title, would the tag have been shown in the tab title?

Comment: Yes, per [the example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356422/all-lines-are-dotted) I spent 20 minutes hunting for and edited onto my answer.